# How do you import bookmarks into Touch browser?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, browser

I've started using Touch 15.04 OTA-13 on a Nexus 4. From what I've read, there isn't a way to import bookmarks. I've saved a bookmarks file from Firefox as HTML and have that on my phone. Neither the browser or file manager can handle it so as to import. I'm not getting any answers to this in the Forums, so I thought I'd ask here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

They are probably stored in /home/phablet/.local/share/webbrowser-app/bookmarks.sqlite

Comment: I've tried to get into that database, but I'm stuck there. For some reason the gvfs mount from the phone to my Ubuntu desktop does not show hidden files, even when that option is enabled. I'd be willing to try to modify the SQL directly (I've worked on databases before and written code to interact with them).

Comment: I've copied that sqlite file over to my desktop and browsed it. I can see the simple schema storing the bookmark.  I've also looked at the Firefox bookmark database schema and it is much more complex. It should be easy to parse the bookmarks.html file from a browser into the sqlite format.

Comment: Leonard, it will be great to do some tool for importing. In similar case I used sqlite plugin for FAR manager and made import manually.